# Is there any point in supporting byte-range requests for VBR (variable bitrate) audio?

Tags: audio, http-headers, server-application

I'm working on a server application which will hand out audio streams. These audio streams are being consumed in web browsers, specifically through the `<audio>` element.

Now, let's say the server application offers MP3 streams. If these MP3 streams are VBR (variable bitrate), is there any use for the server application to support `byte-range` requests at all?

The server application will respond with a `Content-Length` header, but I can't see how the client (browser) will be capable of letting the user seek to any given position in the stream as we're dealing with variable bitrate.

Am I missing something?